# how to caputre data parmeters on click values on graph in jqcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqchart

I am new to jqCharts. Below is the code of data highlighting events . on mouse hover that data is displayed . But i need on click of the values on the graph data parameters are displayed instead of mouse hover .Below is the code

```
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jqChart').jqChart({
            title: "dataHighlighting Event",
            legend: { visible: false },
            animation: { duration: 1 },
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'column',
                    title: 'Column',
                    data: [['A', 46], ['B', 35], ['C', 68], ['D', 30],
                           ['E', 27], ['F', 85], ['D', 43], ['H', 29]],
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                },
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    title: 'Line',
                    data: [['A', 69], ['B', 57], ['C', 86], ['D', 23],
                           ['E', 70], ['F', 60], ['D', 88], ['H', 22]],
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            ]
        });

        $('#jqChart').bind('dataHighlighting', function (e, data) {
            displayDataOptions(data);
        });
    });

    function displayDataOptions(data) {
        var list = $('#listBlock');
        list.children().remove();

        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        list.append('<li>data.chart=' + data.chart + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.series=' + data.series + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.dataItem=[' + data.dataItem + ']</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.index=' + data.index + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.x=' + data.x + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.y=' + data.y + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.shape=' + data.shape + '</li>');
    }
</script>
```

i have used onclick insted of cursor: 'pointer'.But still data paremeters appear on mouse hover . Would anyone please provide help on how to capture data on click of the values of graph .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been doing it like this:

```
function updateChartPos(data){
    if (typeof data != 'undefined') {
      //SET YOUR GLOBAL VARIABLES
    }
  }

$('#jqchart').bind('dataHighlighting', function (e, data) {
            updateChartPos(data);
        });

$(document).on('click', 'canvas', function() {
        //Run your function with globals
});
```

The reason for this is that if you use the standard datapoint click options with jqChart, the user must click directly on the data point for the event to register.

Using a combination of the dataHighlighting binding and a canvas click listener, you allow the user to click anywhere on the graph and it will simply use the last datapoint they have hovered over (which gives them a radius for margin of error in clicking).

Your code would then change to:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jqChart').jqChart({
            title: "dataHighlighting Event",
            legend: { visible: false },
            animation: { duration: 1 },
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'column',
                    title: 'Column',
                    data: [['A', 46], ['B', 35], ['C', 68], ['D', 30],
                           ['E', 27], ['F', 85], ['D', 43], ['H', 29]],
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                },
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    title: 'Line',
                    data: [['A', 69], ['B', 57], ['C', 86], ['D', 23],
                           ['E', 70], ['F', 60], ['D', 88], ['H', 22]],
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            ]
        });

        $('#jqChart').bind('dataHighlighting', function (e, data) {
            updateChartPos(data);
        });
    });

    function updateChartPos(data) {

       window.currentInformation = data;

    }

    function displayDataOptions() {
        var data = window.currentInformation;
        var list = $('#listBlock');
        list.children().remove();

        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        list.append('<li>data.chart=' + data.chart + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.series=' + data.series + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.dataItem=[' + data.dataItem + ']</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.index=' + data.index + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.x=' + data.x + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.y=' + data.y + '</li>');
        list.append('<li>data.shape=' + data.shape + '</li>');
    }

    $(document).on('click', 'canvas', function() {
       displayDataOptions();
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps! jqChart is an amazing library, I've been really happy with it since I bought a license. Check out their forum if you run into other issues - the guys that run it have been really good about any issues I raised.